# cancan and enums only on "show" action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, authorization, cancan

I'm using cancan in my rails 3 application with mysql DB.

When i create a rule based on an enum column i always get AccessDenied only for "show" action. Any idea why?
I use enumerated_attribute to enforce enums in the models and an actual ENUM type column in the database.

Example:
I have a Post that has an enum field privacy with ['PUBLIC','PRIVATE','LOCAL']. I always get AccessDenied when i use this rule:

can :read, Post, :privacy => 'PUBLIC'

Every other rule works perfectly. The above rule also works great on "index" action.

**UPDATE 1:**

My ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, Post, :privacy => 'PUBLIC'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/479